# Webpack proxy in Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I'm trying to proxy an API call in a `.vue` component in `Laravel` project. In the `webpack.mix.js` file, I added:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        "/v1": {
          target: "https://api.example-uat.io/",
          changeOrigin: true
        }
      }
    }
});
```

I run `npm run watch` to auto compile the changes. However, the proxying doesn't seem to work.

```
├─┬ laravel-mix@2.0.0
│ └── webpack@3.11.0  deduped
└── webpack@3.11.0
```

I keep on getting `404  Not found` error upon running it. Seems like the proxying doesn't work.

The Laravel App doesn't have the requested route. That's why it's proxied to an open-ended API server.

Is there any other way to achieve this proxying?

Comment: What exactly is not working in your second code block? Are you sure your target paths are correct?

Comment: @Bart Yes, I tested it with a Vue-Cli project and it worked great. It just isn't working with the Laravel Mix

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same issue.